# How to prevent a command in the zshell from being saved into history?

Tags: command-line, zsh, linux-terminal

In Bash I know putting a space before a command prevents it from being kept in the history, what is the equivalent for the zshell?

Comment: cross-linking to (slightly more involved) bash answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6094/is-there-any-way-to-keep-a-command-from-being-added-to-your-history

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Use the HIST_IGNORE_SPACE option.

```
setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE
```

> man zshoptions
>
> HIST_IGNORE_SPACE
>
> Remove command lines from the history list when the first character on the line is a space, or when  one  of  the expanded  aliases  contains a leading space.  Note that the command lingers in the internal history until the next command is entered before it vanishes, allowing you to briefly reuse or edit the line.  If you  want  to  make  it vanish right away without entering another command, type a space and press return.

Comment: I wish I could do this for all-the-commands-typed-in-a-terminal-window-since-open on OSX. For when you realize that you've been barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: This wasn't working for me, until I read the whole text and realized it's awesomer than bash!!

Comment: And then, for the commands I wanted to prevent, I used aliases and prefixed a space: alias jrnl=" jrnl"

Comment: Is there a way to do this for a block of commands?

Comment: @Yar kill -9 that shell (if it doesn't do line-per-line history file writes)

Comment: @MichaelShigorin Thanks! `kill -9 $$` is indeed fantastic to avoid all the commands issued in current terminal session to be stored in the history.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai You could `unset HISTFILE` prior to your block of commands. You'd need to reset `HISTFILE` afterward or open a new shell to keep commands in your history that you want.

Comment: Small "warning" if you test this locally. If you do a command like `_blah` (`_` as space) to "test" then press the up key or do `Ctrl` + `R` right away or before entering a different command (besides like just pressing enter) then you'll still see the `_blah` there -- but once you run a "real" command it will not be. Just a heads up because sometimes I do this to make sure things don't end up in history and forget this behavior then I get worried. (It's possible this is a bug?)

Comment: @CaptainMan -- as it says right in the answer - "the command lingers in the internal history until the next command is entered before it vanishes, allowing you to briefly reuse or edit the line." Not a bug.

Comment: `unsetopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE`

Comment: Why this config is not set by default?

Answer (score 15):

If you desire more granular control over what's added to ZSH history, you can define the `zshaddhistory` function in `.zshrc`. The following definition uses a regex to define a pattern to ignore:

```
function zshaddhistory() {
  emulate -L zsh
  if ! [[ "$1" =~ "(^ |^ykchalresp|--password)" ]] ; then
      print -sr -- "${1%%$'\n'}"
      fc -p
  else
      return 1
  fi
}
```

Note that the behavior from `man zshopts` under `HIST_IGNORE_SPACE` is still present:

> Note  that  the command lingers in the internal history until the next command is entered before it vanishes, allowing you to briefly reuse or edit the line.

So to test it, you would have to hit an extra `[Enter]`. This removes the command both from the output of `history`, and also the ↑ arrow history.

See this plugin for keeping log entries, but mask sensitive data based on a regex: https://github.com/jgogstad/passwordless-history